# Get separate used memory info from free -m command

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, memory

As the output of the `free -m` command, I get the following:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2496       2260        236          0          5        438
-/+ buffers/cache:       1816        680
Swap:         1949         68       1881
```

I want to get only used memory, like 2260, as output. 
I tried the following command:

```
free -m | grep Mem | cut -f1 -d " "
```

Help me to improve my command.

How can I get it as a percentage, like 35%?

Comment: note that `-m` part is optional and simply converts the output number from kB to mB.

Comment: Concerning the % part: this is how I display my laptop battery in [0.0 - 1.0]: `$(calc -d "$BR / 96000")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for the added question of displaying as percentage (based on jasonwryan's answer):

```
awk '/^Mem/ {printf("%u%%", 100*$3/$2);}' <(free -m)
```

get percentage by diving 3rd field by 2nd and print as an integer (no rounding up!).

**EDIT**: added double '%' in `printf` (the first one escapes the literal character intended for printing).

Comment: @user34571 thanks for pointing out the double `%` issue. You may also want to put these things into comment next time (to get some credits :)).

Answer (score 9):

You can use `awk` without the need for a separate `grep` pipe for this:

```
awk '/^Mem/ {print $3}' <(free -m)
```

Where records/rows are filtered for those beginning with `Mem` and the third field/column (`$3`) is printed for the filtered record.

Answer (score 6):

Or with sed:

```
free -m | sed -n 's/^Mem:\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+/\1/p'
```

Another solution would be:

```
free -m  | grep ^Mem | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

Credits for the second solution got to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143252/how-to-make-the-cut-command-treat-several-sequential-delimiters-as-one).

Comment: It gives me total memory .

Answer (score 4):

with `bash` `free` and `grep` only

```
read junk total used free shared buffers cached junk < <(free -m  | grep ^Mem)
echo $used
```

Answer (score 0):

`FNR =2` is 2nd row of output and `{print $3}` printing the 3rd column which is used

```
free -m | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $3}'
```