# Getting only used memory from free command every few seconds

Tags: shell, scripting, logs, memory, free

It was explained e.g. here:

[Get separate used memory info from free -m command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68526/get-separate-used-memory-info-from-free-m-command)

how to cut the output of `free` command. But I want to do this every few seconds and log it to a file. So I tried:

```
free -g -s2 | sed -n 's/^Mem:\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+/\1/p' >> memory2.log
```

but the file stays empty. Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: it's because the `sed` command never finishes. I will be right back with a solution :)

Comment: You can use the `-u` flag for `sed`. That fixes the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because as far as I know `sed` buffers the input first, that means the command doesn't end so it won't get to the part where it gets appended (`>>`). To fix this simply use the `-u` / `--unbuffered` flag for `sed`:

```bash
free -g -s2 | sed -u -n 's/^Mem:\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+/\1/p' >> memory2.log
```

---

Other solution would be to use a `while` loop:

```bash
while true; do free -g | sed -n 's/^Mem:\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+/\1/p'; sleep 1; done >> memory2.log
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Another solution (that could work on any command and doesn't depend on a specific flag like `-u` for `sed`) is using [`stdbuf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf), for instance: `stdbuf -oL sed -n '...'`. But that's just for general knowledge, if the command supports unbuffering via a flag, it's better to use the command's native capabilities.

Comment: @Pixelbog Is there a way to add Swap to the first sollution, so that I would log the sum of used Mem and Swap?

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk to form a much simpler command.  Awk also uses output buffering, but the `mawk` that's on my Ubuntu desktop supports an option to use line buffering:

```
free -g -s2 | awk -W interactive '/^Mem:/ {print $2}'
```

(Note: on my computer, `awk` is linked to `mawk` via the Debian alternatives subsystem)

If you're going to run a shell loop to invoke `free | awk` then it becomes a *very* simple command:

```
while true; do
  free -g | awk '/^Mem:/ {print $2}' >> /path/to/memory2.log
  sleep 2
done
```