# Logging sum of Mem and Swap from free command output

Tags: scripting, memory, arithmetic, free

In relation to this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/754252/582781

Solution 1:

```
free -g -s2 | sed -u -n 's/^Mem:\s\+[0-9]\+\s\+\([0-9]\+\)\s.\+/\1/p' >> memory.log
```

Is there a way to add Swap to this, so that I would log the sum of used Mem and Swap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
free -g -s2 | stdbuf -o0 awk '/^Mem/ { u = $3 } /^Swap/ { print u + $3 }' >> memory.log
```